# Redirect from empty location in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have nginx proxy and I want all requests to be proxied to another server with the same uri.

Here's what I did:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass https://example.com;
}
```

But I need one exception in this rule - when url is empty (user visits actual / location) I want to proxy this request to https://example.com/index

How do I write a rule for an empty url?

Comment: AFAIK / is the "no URL" request. I suspect you need to use try_files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess, you mean `/` location as this is the “minimal” location. You could use “exact match” (`=`) modifier:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass https://example.com;
}

location = / {
    proxy_pass https://example.com/index;
}
```